# An Android app that changes the notification tone depending on a text message's content

Tags: gratis, android, audio, notification, sms

Is there a free Android app (4.0+) that changes the notification sound you get when you receive a text if most of the text message is a 'confirmation'?

By 'confirmation', I mean words like 'ok', 'yes', 'fine', 'ya', etc.

So, some examples:

> Yes <sub>different notification tone</sub>
>
> I'm going to be home late. OK? <sub>default notification tone</sub>
>
> Yeah that's fine <sub>different notification tone</sub>

This is basically because I often send messages to people where replies are pretty short - yes or no. However, the 'yes'’s can be written differently - and it takes effort to take the phone out of your pocket, unlocking it, just to see 'yes'.

It needs to be:

- free
- runnable on Android 4.0+
- have a customizable notification tone

Comment: Not a direct answer, but at least a hint: Tasker might be able to do this (not free), so other automation solutions like Llama (free) are at least worth to be looked at.

Comment: I wasn't sure how I'd get tasker to read the message... I do have tasker tho.

Comment: In that case, please check with the [Tasker UserGuide on Variables](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/variables.html). If we're speaking of SMS here, `%SMSRB` holds the message body, and you can use [pattern matching](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/matching.html) on it. You will need to play a little here (`%SMSRB ~= *yes*` might have too many false positives, so you might need `~R` regex matching instead).

Comment: Fingers crossed! Don't forget to keep us updated :)